# How to Look Up Custom Taxonomy Value by Post_id and Update Table Using Mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I've been working on this for hours, but can't figure it out. Long story short, I'm working on a Wordpress site and imported about 1M listings so far for various professionals. They're organized based on their specialty (e.g., plumber, mechanic, nurse, etc.). Only about 70% of them have properly been indexed, so a lot of them aren't being picked up by the search feature on the website. I thought it'd be a good idea to dump the remainder into a different table and insert them.

I have every field imported in a copy table for almost all of the columns I need except for Specialties and Business Affiliations. How those are organized is very confusing. I can't figure out how to transfer over the values for specific taxonomy values.  There is only one specialty for each professional, but may/may not have more than one affiliation.

wp_term_relationships

```
   object_id   term_taxomony_id  term_order
      5705         53192          1
      5705         55596          1
```

wp_term_taxonomy

```
   term_taxonomy_id    term_id   taxonomy     description   parent  count
   53192               53186     hospitals                          121
   55596               55590     specialty                          57479
```

wp_terms

```
   term_id   name                      slug                      term_group    order
   53186     Texas Orthopedic Hospital texas-orthopedic-hospital 0             0
   55590     Physician Assistant       physician-assistant       0             0
```

Joins are confusing enough without having to deal with the structure of the wordpress database.  Seems like I need to join 3 tables. I know how to do this with vlookup, but now I'm committed to learning the process using mysql.

```
UPDATE wp_leftover_pros_temp wp
JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON (wp.`post_id` = wtr.`object_id`)
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON (wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`) 
JOIN wp_terms wt ON (wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`)  
SET wp.specialty  = wt.name
WHERE wp.post_id = wtr.object_id AND wtr.term_taxonomy_id = '55596'
```

Entering that code correctly updates every match for the specialty (55590 = physician assistant). If I take that out the remaining records are updated with the default value, which appears to be gender for some reason. I have over 400 specialties.  I was hoping it would match each post_id to a specialty, and find the correct value. I'm not sure why it's designed this way.

Is there a way to do update the specialty for each post without having to create 400+ update statements?